# Can we learn Django for a python beginner?

Tags: python, django

Now, I'm learning python but I'm PHP web developer. I don't interest about terminal and windows programming. I only want to do web development. So, Can I learn Django ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can. I started learning Django with very little Python knowledge too. As long as you have another language behind your belt, preferably a web based one (as you do), I don't think you're biting off too much at once.

Python's a pretty easy language to pick up too. Just have to get used to the significant white space and lack of semi-colons :P

Comment: Yeah, same story with me. Just open up the django book (search "django book") and you'll be writing stuff in 10 minutes..

Comment: Yeah!!! I think so. Ok. thank I'm ready to go Django

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to disagree with previous answers. You *could* learn Python by learning Django, but I don't think it's a very good idea. You won't really understand why things are the way they are, or how things really work.

My advice would be to follow a Python tutorial first - if you're an experienced programmer already then [Dive Into Python](http://diveintopython.net) is an excellent one - and then run through the Django tutorial. You'll be in a much better shape if you do.

Comment: I don't think learning Python with Django is the best way to learn Python... but if your goal is to make a web app, you can do it. Then go back and do some straight Python when you have the time.

Comment: +1. Totally agree. I had a really basic knowledge of Python when I started learning Django, but the struggles start appearing after the learning materials got into more practical subjects. Python is more than a programming language because it has it's own philosophy of how things should be done. Starting learning Python first is just imperative.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can!
Django requires minimal knowledge about using python from the command line, but if you're comfortable with that, then there shouldn't be an issue. Django has excellent documentation and a good tutorial aimed at beginners that does not expect you to be a high-level Python programmer.

Here's the link to the beginner's tutorial for Django: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Why do you need to know how use python from the CL? `./manage syncdb` hardly counts! :D

Comment: Very true, but it seemed only fair to throw in a warning :P I'll change the wording to "minimal"
Who knows. Some people have absolutely no knowledge of how to navigate through folders on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

I tried starting just by going through the [Django tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/#intro-tutorial01), which got me going fast, but without enough Python knowledge, I got stuck when starting to write my own first app. Python terms like "tuples", "lists", and "dictionaries" were new to me and I didn't have any background to understand how and why to use them.

Spending time to go through the free [Google Python Class](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/) was well worth it and made many things clear. Otherwise, too much of what's in Django will seem like magic and you'll get stuck as soon as you need to write some functions to manipulate your data.

In short, I found that I could learn Django & Python concurrently, but not just by focusing on Django alone. Besides, learning Python is fun in itself and won't take you more than a day or two to learn the basics. I liked the Google class because it has video lectures and good exercises that focus on the practical use of Python.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Django it's good way to learn Python in fact. Django allows you to do nice things in a short time, which might be good motivation to dive into that language.